# Sequence of bounded Lebesgue integrals equals a finite integral

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm struggling to answer the following question. I've been given an increasing sequence of measurable functions $\left(f_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}}$ with each $f_n: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}$ defined on $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure, and we assume that $\left(\int_S f_n d \lambda\right)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}}$ is bounded.

We need to show that $\left(f_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}}$ converges pointwise on $S$ to a non-negative measurable function $f$ on $S$ which is finite almost everywhere (i.e. the Lebesgue measure of the subset where $f$ is not finite is equal to zero), and also that
$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_S f_n d \lambda=\int_S f d \lambda<\infty.
$$

Anyone know how to answer this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is almost exactly the monotone convergence theorem. What's the problem?